# AWS lambda throttle concurrent invocations from a specific event source

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I've created dynamic sqs standard queues which are used as an event source for my lambda function invocation. Whenever any message is pushed into the queues the lambda function is invoked. Now, i want to add some throttling on my lambda function like a single event source can have only one active invocation of lambda at a time. There are some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55200276/9014038) but they only work on throttling overall lambda concurrency.

Comment: The throttling in the anwser you've linked applies to specific function, not "overall lambda concurrency".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Lambda functions can also be triggered from an Amazon SQS **FIFO** queue.

From [New for AWS Lambda – SQS FIFO as an event source | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-sqs-fifo-as-an-event-source/):

> In SQS FIFO queues, using more than one `MessageGroupId` enables Lambda to scale up and process more items in the queue using a greater concurrency limit. Total concurrency is equal to or less than the number of unique MessageGroupIds in the SQS FIFO queue.

So, it seems that if you specify all messages with the same `MessageGroupId` and a batch size of `1`, then it will only process one message at a time.

Comment: My use case has changed but i think this should've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From [Managing Concurrency for a Lambda Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html):

> When a function has reserved concurrency, no other function can use that concurrency. Reserved concurrency also limits the maximum concurrency for the function, and applies to the function as a whole, including versions and aliases.

Therefore, **reserved concurrency** can be used to limit the number of concurrent executions of a *specific* AWS Lambda function.

Comment: I'm not trying to limit the concurrent executions of a lambda function but concurrent executions by a specific event source. An event source can have only one invocation at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes it can be done but only in a roundabout way.

When you have a Lambda function set as a triggered function on an SQS queue, the Lambda service polls the queue and handles the receiving and deletion of a message from the queue. The only control you have over how many messages the Lambda service reads and how many instances of your function the Lambda service invokes is (a) batch size, and (b) function concurrency.

Neither of these will help you when applied directly to your function, because setting the batch size to a small number (e.g. 1) will result in more instances being started (takes longer to process 1 message at a time), and setting it to a high number may not be desirable in your case, and if it is then it still won't help if the number of messages is higher than the batch size or they are received frequently and your function is already busy processing the previous batch. And you already said function concurrency is a no go because you only want to limit the concurrency from a source, not overall.

So here's a way it can be accomplished: create another function with a concurrency limit of 1, set it as the triggered function instead of your function. That function will receive messages, and it in turn will invoke your function with said message(s). It will wait for your function to return before returning itself. Only when the new function returns can it receive another message/batch from the Lambda service, and invoke your function again. So your "real" function has no overall concurrency limit, but there is only ever one instance invoked/running at a time from your SQS source (via the new function).

Comment: Just to clarify, as the middleware function has concurrency limit of 1, so if another queue tries to invoke it will it be invoked as its already running?

Comment: If another queue tries to invoke the middleware function? Yes it will fail as it's already running. You'd need one of these per queue/function combination. It's certainly not ideal but it's one way to do it.